# Does rotating the focus ring in AF mode cause any harm?

Tags: lens, autofocus, canon-600d

If I rotate focus ring in AF mode, does this hurt the camera or lens? My friend today rotated the ring 1/2 times before I saw him on Autofocus on my Canon 600d with lens: EF-S 18-55mm 1:3.5-5.6 III.  What damage could possibly have been caused?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Canon EF-S 18-55mm F/3.5-5.6 III does not have a quick-shift autofocus system (although the STM version of the 18-55mm does). It does have an internal focus system like all EF-S lenses. This means that you can damage the lens but not the camera that way.

In all likelihood, the lens will not be damage though but in the worst case, you lost an extremely cheap lens which is a great opportunity to get something decent :) Simply try to use autofocus on subjects close and far to see if it still works. Image quality won't be affected any other way, so AF will or not.

Comment: I am so poor i worked 3 months for this.. so you are telling me that even in the worst case scenario its just the FOCUS that is broken , not the quality,light receiving and the many others thinks , just the focus? and by the way THANKS YOU ALL guys you help so much!

Comment: Yes, right, image quality should not be affected in any other way. Noise, color, dynamic-range, all that are dictated by the camera and since the Canon EF mount has no mechanical connection, this damage is extremely unlikely to affect the camera.

Comment: Last question thank you a lot, let say i broke it and i am not able to AF, can i still focus perfectly on MF or the broken parts will affect even the MF

Comment: If its the motor than you can still focus manually.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know EF-S 18-55mm III do not have FTM (full time manual mode). So "playing" with focus ring with AF mode can burn the motor inside. And such action should be avoided

In worst case scenario you will not be able to autofocus

Comment: can you tell me if the worst possible outcome was done when he rotated it, what would be changed in the photos of my camera :/?

Comment: @Stanley if you cannot tell a difference, it's likely that there isn't any. Does your camera still work? Does it still auto focus?

Comment: In worst case scenario you will not be able to autofocus

Comment: THANKS A LOT ,i am a paronoid guy by nature and i think there is a little more blury image, and yes the camera stil autofocus perfectly i just think the overall quelity is worst? but if this is true about the worst case scenario is just not autofocus i am fine

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the 18-55mm with the STM designation? I am pretty sure lenses with the STM (stepping) will let you take over focus without any will effects. The lens works by wire, by which I mean when you turn the focus ring you are not turning any gears but are sending an electronic signal to change the focus of the lens. If it is not an stm lens that is not good and it may have been damaged. Have you taken any pictures since the incident? Make sure you double check your pictures on a monitor zoomed in to check your focus. Do not rely on the camera's lcd screen. Worst case scenario you have to buy another lens and at least it was not too expensive (relatively speaking to the L line of lenses).

Comment: well damn... sorry i am into photography from 2 weeks... how to check if its STM

Comment: @Stanley, this sequence of symbols (STM) should be printed on lens. And actually should be part of the name of the lens

Comment: I just noticed that you wrote your lens is the mark III. I do not think they make a mark III with the stepping motor which probably means it is not a STM lens.

Comment: There was a new Q posted for this.  Dpreview points out that the focus ring turns with the autofocus and is not clutched or "by wire". Basically if the ring turns by itself, don't fight it.